# How to set a timeout with a default soap response in soap producer?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, soap

I know that timeout is a property of client , but we need to **send a response in 2 minutes** from spring soap endpoint.

How to timeout in spring soap and send a default response within a specified time from soap producer app?

Container : Tomcat

```
@Endpoint
public class SOAPEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

    private Repository repository;

    

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getData")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Response getCountry(@RequestPayload SampleRequest request) {
    Response response = new Response();
        response.setCountry(repository.retrieveData(request.getParam())); // this lines takes 5 minutes to respond

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a configuration-based solution, but here are possible library-based solutions:

- Some DBs lets you to set a query timeout, so if it's available for you, it seems like a good approach. If you will specify the DB you use, I will dig into it.
- You can use the [TimeLimiter of resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/timeout):

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
    GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
    TimeLimiter timeLimiter = TimeLimiter.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    try {
        Country country = timeLimiter.executeFutureSupplier(() ->
           CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName())));
        response.setCountry(country);

        return response;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // handle timeout.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // handle general error.
    }

    return null; // You may want to replace this.
}
```

The Producer code above is originated from - https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
and was tested against the Consumer - https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/